# Android collec flow in viewmodel

Tags: android, viewmodel

Всем доброго времени суток! Стоит задача отображать страницу авторизации, если пользователь не авторизирован, т.е., выполнить условную навигацию.

Данные хранятся в `datastore` в `viewmodel`, в методе `init` происходит сбор (collect), и выполняется условный переход (после коллекта не выполняется), который заставляет `SplashScreen` исчезать:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val splashScreen = installSplashScreen()

    setContent {
        AppTheme() {
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
            ) {
                val model: UserViewModel = viewModel(
                    factory = UserViewModel.provideFactory(LocalContext.current)
                )
                val hasLoggedIn by model.hasLoggedIn.collectAsState()
                val status by model.status.collectAsState()

                splashScreen.setKeepOnScreenCondition { !status }

                if (hasLoggedIn) {
                    MyAppNavHost()
                } else {
                    LoginScreen()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class UserViewModel(context: Context) : ViewModel() {
companion object {
    fun provideFactory(context: Context): ViewModelProvider.Factory =
        object : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
            override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
                return UserViewModel(context) as T
            }
        }
}

private val dataStore = AppDataStore(context)

private val _hasLoggedIn: MutableStateFlow<Boolean> = MutableStateFlow(false)
val hasLoggedIn = _hasLoggedIn.asStateFlow()

private val _status: MutableStateFlow<Boolean> = MutableStateFlow(false)
val status = _status.asStateFlow()

init {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

        dataStore.userExists.collect {
            _hasLoggedIn.value = it
        }

        // не выполняется
        _status.value = true
    }
}
}

val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(name = "settings")

class AppDataStore(context: Context) {
    companion object {
        val USER_EXISTS = booleanPreferencesKey("user_exists")
    }

    val userExists: Flow<Boolean> = context.dataStore.data
       .map {
           it[USER_EXISTS] ?: false
        }
 
}
```

Comment: и не будет выполняться. у вас горячий флоу, а это значит, что его "прослушка" никогда сама по себе не закончится. возможно, вам подойдет метод `Flow.first()` который возьмет первое поступившие значение.